# Connection loses on data-send. Server receives RST, ACK after handshake

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, windows-server-2008, wireshark

I've got a simple TCP-server hosted on 64bit windows server 2008 r2. TCP-server just receives connection and replies to incoming data with recieved message(echo). There are about 600-700 clients who try connect and send some information. And the problem is: server loses almost all of connections(about 90%) when data is sended from client to server(First 15-20 connections have been performed normallly). I've sniffed the TCP-traffic with Whireshark. 
From server side log is:

```
 +--------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
 | Source       | Destination  | Info                           |
 +--------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
 | 1. client ip | server ip    | [SYN] **Handshake step1**      |
 | 2. server ip | client ip    | [SYN, ACK] **Handshake step2** |
 | 3. client ip | server ip    | [ACK] **Handshake step3**      |
 | 4. client ip | server ip    | [RST, ACK] **Loses connection**|
 +--------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

From client side log is:

```
 +--------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
 | Source       | Destination  | Info                           |
 +--------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
 | 1. client ip | server ip    | [SYN] **Handshake step1**      |
 | 2. server ip | client ip    | [SYN, ACK] **Handshake step2** |
 | 3. client ip | server ip    | [ACK] **Handshake step3**      |
 | 4. client ip | server ip    | [PSH, ACK] Message             |
 | 5. client ip | server ip    | [PSH, ACK] CRLF message        |
 | 6. server ip | client ip    | [RST, ACK] **Loses connection**|
 +--------------+--------------+--------------------------------+
```

In both cases the «Reset cause» is: \000\000\000......\000
The connection did not lose when we're connecting from local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was that, provider changed tariff plan without any notice. New tariff plan limited the maximum number of connections.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related to your code, but I do have several questions:
1. What is the network speed between client and the server? Are there any packets lost for other applications? What's the size of the message sent from client?
2. How long is it between the RST received and the handshake finishes (server) or message sent (client)?
3. Do you know if there are any firewalls between the client and server? You also said it worked well on LAN. The China GFW often does so.

Comment: 1. Server network capacity 1 Gbit/s. Other applications dont lose packages. Messages size about 100-150 bytes(shor messages). 2. Connection loses immediately. 3. Only windows firewall, but I had disabled it.

Comment: Now it seems to be dropped due to some limitation. When you say 90% drop, are these connections come in in a very short period of time? Did you try waiting for some time to see if it will be successful? Another question is for the successful cases, did you close the connections after server responded?

Comment: Yes, I tried to wait for some time - the result was same. I do not close the connection after server responded, the connection should be opened for message exchange.

Comment: What I meant was - to stop the client, wait for a while(30 minutes), then let the client send connection requests.

Comment: We can not stop clients. They are autonomous and geographically distributed